# how to get java docs attached to my java projects?

Tags: java, javadoc

How to get ino about the `Java` classes and methods. when I use the `auto Assist` to add a method or interface normally in Android I receive ino about them, but when I use `java` it seems the javadocs attached to my java proojects are not existing ad i always receive the below message

please let e know how to solve this.

```
Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be 
found.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the source code, place caret on the class with the missing javadoc, and press F3.
Then you will see 
[image]

From here you wil lbe able to add the javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in eclipse, locate the .jar in the JRE System Library under your project. Right Click -> Javadoc Location. Download the docs and specify the location of the archive.